# Stretch two buttons full width on the same line - Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

If I have two button components (that have a btn-block class, though they don't have to), how can I have them in the same row, full width both? I know how to achieve this 'manually'. The thing is, I have to do this using only utility classes. So no additional CSS, if possible of course.

Please, help! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to have "two buttons full width on the same row" as they would overlap each other and, quite frankly, serve no real purpose.

This might not also be the BEST way of doing it, but to achieve something that may come close to what you want using Bootstrap 4 could be done by:

Having two buttons, 50% width, on the same row

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-6">
  <!-- BUTTON 1 HERE -->
 </div>
 <div class="col-6">
 <!-- BUTTON 2 HERE -->
 </div>    
</div>
```

Or having both buttons at 100% width, but different rows

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-12">
  <!-- BUTTON 1 HERE -->
 </div>
 <div class="col-12">
 <!-- BUTTON 2 HERE -->
 </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, I agree in addition it been an issue before at bootstrap, [https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/13647] (btn-block class for different breakpoints #13647) [https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/20617] (Responsive .btn-block #20617).

Answer (score 0):

I'm using **Bootstrap 5** while developing **Razor View Page** in **ASP.NET MVC** project. I solved a similar problem as follows:

```css
.myButtonStyle{
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary myButtonStyle" role="button">Change Image</a>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-success disabled myButtonStyle" role="button">Save</a>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger disabled myButtonStyle" role="button">Discard</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

The picture below contains the images of the buttons on the same line:

[image: Application Picture]

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.
I have added 2 col in a row and used btn-block for button class.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">button#1</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">button#2</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```